# Does Content Query Webpart make the server become slow?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my new project, I have used a lot of Content Query Webparts (CQWP) and then I found that the site was becoming slower and slower when visited with the increasing number of CQWPs.The question I want to ask is:

1. Does a CQWP take a lot of server resources that make the site slow for visitors?
2. If I want to query the lists and customize the style of output then can I do it without a CQWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For your first question

My answer is : It depends on the several things not only on the number of CQWP on the page.

Let me explain :

The CQWP has so many things to do like fetching data from the List which may be Sharepoint list or custom list ,the resource utilization depends on the logic applied to fetch the data from the list , by saying this I mean the amount of data to be fetched and the Logic complexity to get that data also make sense for the server resource utilization..

For example, If you have class which perform complex logic to get the data like comaprision , if else condition and ForEach Loops  and the amount of data avaliable in list is large then it is obvious that it will take more resources from the server.

I hope you get my point

### For Second question

My Answer is  : You can use CQWp or DVWP(Data View Web Part), but be sure when to use which one.

To get more Idea about both of this take a look at this link

> http://www.sharepointblog.co.uk/2012/06/data-view-web-part-vs-content-query-web-part/

Comment: It is a Enterprise Portal Project , so I need to query data from List millious times . As you said,the CQWP is the best choise to do this?Not only in the page, the whole sites's pages were made up of CQWP.

Comment: If you query a data millions times that's not the problem the logic or the Resource optimization is the big deal.. make the code work as it does not require to trip again again and to the server to get data. and avoid the use of Looping if possible on large amount of data.

Comment: May I ask you another related question ?  How can I make a connection by CQWP ?  I want to realize a "Function" called "Search" in my page in order to filter the result queried out by the CQWP

Comment: Do you want to Filter the Results Got from CQWP ? using your function >? Can you elaborate it more ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link may be you have to use custom XSLT with function to filter the output of CQWP.

> http://blog.mastykarz.nl/extending-content-query-web-part-xslt-custom-functions/